# I want to make a number increment using winform MVP pattern in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, label, mvp, flowlayoutpanel

Hi I'm practicing using winform MVP pattern in C#.

I made Models, Presenters and Views folders, and they has a each class.
(Models has Data.cs, Presenters has Datapresenter.cs and View have interface.cs and Form.cs)

I used 'FlowLayoutPanel'. and I made Label to make numbers. Like this.

My progress so far.

WinForm I made.

[image: WinForm what I made]

Here is Data.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LayoutSample.Models
{
    public class Data
    {

        public string label { get; set; }

        public string CalculateArea()
        {
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is DataPresenter.cs (Presenter)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using LayoutSample.Models;
using LayoutSample.Views;

namespace LayoutSample.Presenters
{
    public class DataPresenter
    {
        IFlowLabel LabelView;

        public DataPresenter(IFlowLabel view)
        {
            LabelView = view;
        }

        public void CalculateArea()
        {
            Data data = new Models.Data();
            data.label = string.Copy(LabelView.label);
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
           for ( int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
           {
               for (int j=1; j<101;j++)
               {
                   Label label = new Label();
                   label.Text = j.ToString();              
                   Console.WriteLine(label);
               }
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
           }
       });
            th.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is interface.cs(View)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LayoutSample.Views
{
    public interface IFlowLabel
    {
        string label { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and this is Form.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using LayoutSample.Models;
using LayoutSample.Presenters;
using LayoutSample.Views;

namespace LayoutSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IFlowLabel
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        string IFlowLabel.label
        {
            get
            {
                return flowLayoutPanel1.ToString();
            }

            set
            {
                if (flowLayoutPanel1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        flowLayoutPanel1.Text = value;
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Text = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.AutoSize = false;
                label.Width = 50;
                label.Text = i.ToString();
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            DataPresenter presenter = new DataPresenter(this);
            presenter.CalculateArea();
        }
    }
}
```

From here, I want to make the numbers increasing.

How could I increase them at same time?

I can watch the numbers increasing via console, but I can't see the change in WimForm. How can I bring the increment to WinForm same as the result of console??

Answer (score 0):

You cant increase the numbers because the numbers are hardcoded and applied to the labels from the code below. Specifically the for loops i.ToString().

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.AutoSize = false;
                label.Width = 50;
                label.Text = i.ToString();
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            DataPresenter presenter = new DataPresenter(this);
            presenter.CalculateArea();
        }
```

If you want to increment the values the strings contain then you have to do something to the labels text itself, I am not sure where you are incrementing the values and seeing that in console.

```
label.Text = i.ToString() + addedValue;
```

Try calling the forms refresh method if the labels are altered.